# How can I override the title of a GitLab wiki page?

Tags: gitlab, wiki, gollum-wiki

I'm am editing pages in a GitLab project wiki.

If I name a page "first-last", the URL is "project/wikis/first-last" and the page title is rendered in sentence case as "First last". If I name a page "first-(last)", the URL is "project/wikis/first-(last)" and the page title is rendered in sentence case as "First (last)".

I want the URL to be "project/wikis/first-last" and the page title to be "First (last)". Thus, I want to override the page title.

My understanding is that GitLab project wikis run on [Gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum). [According to the Gollum docs](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/wiki#page-titles) page titles can be overridden with one of two methods:

1. Enable `--h1-title`. The first H1-level title on the page will override the page title.
2. Use the metadata directive. If the first line of the page is `<!-- --- title: My page title -->`, the given value will override the page title.

I don't have access to option 1. I tried option 2 and nothing happened.

How can I override the title of a GitLab wiki page?

Comment: Looks like they are working on it: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29043

Comment: It can be quite annoying in some languages that the hyphen disappears in page titles. In Germany, there is the somewhat pejorative term [*Deppenleerzeichen*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deppenleerzeichen) for spaces in compound words.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find, there might not be a way to do it. I haven't tried using that Gollum flag, yet.

The GitLab documentation has [this section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/wikis.html#notes-on-gollum):

> ### Notes on Gollum
>
> We only use Gollum as a storage abstraction layer, to handle the mapping between wiki page slugs and files in the repository.
>
> When rendering wiki pages, we don’t use Gollum at all and instead go through a [custom Banzai pipeline](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/banzai/pipeline/wiki_pipeline.rb). This adds some [wiki-specific markup](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#wiki-specific-markdown), such as Gollum’s `[[link]]` syntax.
>
> Because we do not make use of most of Gollum’s features, we plan to move away from it entirely at some point. [See this epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/2381) for reference.