# How to hide page title in GitLab Wiki?

Tags: gitlab, markdown, hide, title, wiki

I'm writing a wiki in another language, but I make links in English.

For example, in main page of GitLab-Wiki I see "**Home**",and if I create new page, called "**CARS**", I'll see **CARS** on top of new page.

So, I want to hide title from the page, which I created, cause sometimes my link could be `home/blabla1234/cadfd`
And every the page `home` has title: **Home**,
page `blabla1234` has title: **blabla1234** etc.

I googled it, and couldn't find any answer on my question. Maybe someone help me with this issue.

Comment: I suspect the answer will be "you can't hide the title" but I don't know that. I wonder though why you feel the need to do this? Would changing your title to `<englishTitle> (<otherLanguageTitle>)` so that your other language reader is informed AND you still have your English title? I don't really follow "_cause sometimes my link could be home/blabla1234/cadfd And every the page home has title: Home, page blabla1234 has title: blabla1234 etc._" What's the issue?

Comment: If you write wiki in Russian, Chineese or some other language, but links are in English.
For Example: I want to write about Functions  in Russian, but links will stay in English. 
Page link: ~wiki/logarithmic-functions
Text: Логарифмические функции.

Comment: Sorry I don't know whether you can "hide the page title" - doubtful. Also, I can't understand why you feel the need to do this. Hopefully others can be more helpful.

Comment: @ScottWelker
there are Wiki, but it is in German language. But link to new pages are in English.
So, for example, for page [Funktionen](Functions) we get page title in English.
So, it will be Functions... But I wanted to have a link on English language, but page title on German. 
In this example, I can use links on German. But what if I want a create a page [Функции](Functions), but it'll get me new page with title Functions (on English)...

Comment: I noticed this seemingly similar question, [How can I override the title of a GitLab wiki page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419354/how-can-i-override-the-title-of-a-gitlab-wiki-page). Perhaps it will provide a suitable answer.